# Oracle update only stored procedure with NHibernate via named query

Tags: nhibernate, oracle11g, nhibernate-mapping

I have an Oracle stored procedure that does only an update. It is a legacy stored proc and I must use it. It cannot be changed.

I can call and execute it from C# with Nhibernate fine as follows:

```
var query = Session.CreateSQLQuery("call myPackage.mySproc(:param1, :param2, :param3)");
query.SetInt64("param1", 123456);
query.SetInt64("param2", 654321);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

I would prefer to use a named query if possible. I've tried the following:

```
Session
.GetNamedQuery("myNamedQuery")
.SetInt64("param1", 123456)
.SetInt64("param2", 654321)
.ExecuteUpdate();
```

where my named query looks like this:

```
<sql-query name="myNamedQuery">

        { call myPackage.mySproc(:param1, :parm2) }
    </sql-query>
```

When I try this, I get the error:

> could not execute native bulk manipulation query

with inner exception:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'mySproc' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored

Now I have of course double checked my parameter list, it matches in the code, the mapping xml and the sproc itself.

Am I way off? Should this be possible? Do I need a  in the mapping even though there is no return data? it only executes a SQL update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<sql-query name="myNamedQuery">
        { call myPackage.mySproc(:param1, :param2, :param3) }
</sql-query>
```

Answer (score 0):

**18.2.2.1. Rules/limitations for using stored procedures**

...
*For Oracle the following rules apply:

**A function must return a result set.** The first parameter of a procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set. This is done by using a SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9i or later. In Oracle you need to define a REF CURSOR type, see Oracle literature.*

[Chapter 18. Native SQL](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html)